# Combining arrays into a url string

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsarray

So I'm building an array of url strings using extensions. I have two arrays of extensions and Im a little bit confused on how to combine them.

I am trying to produce an array of string objects with the following format:

```
http://mywebsite.com/images/places/extention1/extention1
http://mywebsite.com/images/places/extention2/extention2
```

and so on...

When I try to combine them the way I know how I end up with the full array stuck in the place holders

```
http://mywebsite.com/images/places/full array1/full array 2
```

but what I'm really trying to do is build an array of those URL strings from the other two arrays

i know this is super simple but I haven't found any documentation on combining them into a skeleton string.

Comment: Add some code otherwise it is hard to help you!

Comment: Post at least your initial values and the result you want, then we can guide you from start to finish.  Currently we have no idea what you are given, we only know the end result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would do the trick:

```
NSMutableArray *urlArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSArray *extensions = @[@"extension1", @"extension2", @"extension3"];
NSString *urlString = @"http://mywebsite.com/images/places/";

for (NSString *extension in extensions) {
    NSString *combined = [[urlString stringByAppendingPathComponent:extension] stringByAppendingPathComponent:extension];
    [urlArray addObject:combined];
}
```

Comment: That string format is invalid. Why was this accepts as-is?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is it invalid?

Comment: Try it. See what happens. What are all of the extra double-quotes and extra `@` signs for?

Comment: Fair enough.  It does run fine either way, although removing the extra characters does make it a bit cleaner.  I edited the answer to reflect that.

Comment: @DanaK I edited your answer to use a simpler iteration syntax, and also to use the `NSString` methods that are specifically meant for tacking path components together.

Comment: @DaveDeLong thanks...Ive never used that approach before.  Very cool.

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of ways to do this but it could be as simple as:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"http://mywebsite.com/images/places/extention1/extention1", @"http://mywebsite.com/images/places/extention1/extention2", nil];
```

Comment: the two arrays of extensions are being pulled out of a dictionary so i don't want to just initiate it with the strings i want to build them.